# How to manage list with dedicated add and remove button?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to create a view like shown in Image with add and remove `ImageButton`. On click of any of these will start new activity and get contact detail and set/replace on the clicked index.

[image: screenshot]

For Example If I click on 1st green button It will add contact photo and name in 1st row and like-wise for others. I am able to start Activity to get contact information but **I experiencing difficulty to manage this layout and set click event on this.**
Right now I am using 3 different `RelativeLayout` with all distinct Row Components. and I know It will restrict me to facilitate upto 3.

so here is my questions :

1. How can I make a UI so that I can grow this list how much I want(for as of now 3 is ok).
2. How to use add and remove button which will work for there row only.
3. I also want to display contact number just below the name of contact.
4. on click of any row will show its detail.

I'll appreciate any suggestion for better UI which can fulfill above requirement.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How can I make a UI so that I can grow this list how much I want(for as of now 3 is ok).

Use a `ListView` with a `CustomAdapter`. This will allow you to show as many rows as necessary. Within the `getView()` method. Create a separate `layout` that will be inflated in your `Adapter` class that will look something like

```
 <ImageView .../>
 <TextView .../>
 <ImageButton .../>
 <ImageButton .../>
```

> 2.How to use add and remove button which will work for there row only.

Set the `onClick` inside the `getView()` method of the `CustomAdapter` you are going to create

[Adapter Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

[ListView Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: I want to start a new activity to get result on click of `ImageButton` but `StartActivityForResult` and `Intent` is undefined in `getView()`. `Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactListActivity.class);startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_CONTACT);` this is what I am doing.

Comment: Add an `onListItemClick()` to your `Activity` from there. If you can't get it to work then you will need to post your code in your OP. You also can set an `onClick()` on your `ImageButton` in your `getView()`

Comment: ok I am able to `startAcitvityForResult()` in `getView()` but `onActivityResult()` defined in adapterclass is not being called. should I move it to Activity class to be called? If yes, how can I identify position of `listItem` that was clicked.

Comment: Create a member variable to the `Activity` and assign it to the position clicked when an item is selected.

Comment: please tell me where I can upload my code to review. I still haven't get my code work as I want.

Comment: You can either post a new question with the relevant code or I guess you can add it to your OP

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33659/discussion-between-user2376920-and-codemagic)

Comment: @user2376920 Sorry, had to step away and work on something. Did you get it working?

Comment: And to answer your question, just a user like you